# How does 'this' refer to a parent class?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how does inheritance work in JavaScript. I'm quite confused on how does 'this' keyword behave.

I provided the actual code I'm trying to understand that shows class relationships.

```
class AAA {
  xxx() {
    return 2;
  }

  yyy() {
    return 2;
  }

  zzz() {
    return this.xxx() / 2;
  }
}

class BBB extends AAA {
  xxx() {
    return super.xxx() * 2;
  }
}

class CCC extends BBB {
  yyy() {
    return super.yyy() + this.xxx();
  }
  www() {
    return this.xxx() - this.zzz();
  }
}

class DDD extends AAA {
  yyy() {
    return super.yyy() + this.xxx();
  }
  www() {
    return this.zzz() * this.yyy();
  }
}

let c = new CCC();

console.log(c.www()); // 2
```

First I'll explain on my own understanding. Please do correct me if I'm wrong. Additionally, if you don't mind let's agree that '->' means 'refers to' for simplicity.

```
1 c.www() -> CCC.www()
2 CCC.www() -> return this.xxx() - this.zzz()
3     this.xxx() -> BBB.xxx()
4         BBB.xxx() -> return super.xxx() * 2
5             super.xxx() -> AAA.xxx()
                4
6     this.zzz() -> AAA.zzz()
7        AAA.zzz() -> return this.xxx() / 2
8            this.xxx() -> BBB.xxx()
9                BBB.xxx() -> return super.xxx() * 2
10                   super.xxx() -> AAA.xxx()
                        2
// 4 - 2 = 2
```

If what I explained is correct. Then on line 2, how does `this.xxx()` and  `this.zzz()` refer to the parent class? Additionally on line 7, how did `this.xxx()` refer to class BBB?

Comment: `this` refers to the object, the instance created by `new`.  The properties on the parent class prototypes are looked up automatically; that's how prototype inheritance works.

Comment: [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) explains how it works.

Comment: Do you understand in `class A { foo() {} }`, `class B extends A {}` why `new B().foo()` works even though `B` doesn’t declare a `foo`?

Comment: @Ry- `class B` inherits `class A`'s function. So, whether or not I have `this` if there is no `foo()` in `class B` it will automatically refer to the parent class?

Answer (score 1):

All JavaScript objects have a prototype.  You can think of this as a hidden link (or visible depending on your environment) to another object to resolve references to any property (including functions) not defined directly on the object itself.

I find the class syntax (really just sugar) to imply class-based inheritance and thus confusing the real mechanism under the cover.

While old, I still find this explanation one of the best:
http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/02/22/a-plain-english-guide-to-javascript-prototypes/

I would also read just about any article on inheritance by Eric Elliot.